# Laravel 5.3 - scheduled task not working

Tags: php, laravel, cron

I am trying to run a cron function every day but it is not getting executed. I have setup both artisan command for executing it and a cron scheduled task, the artisan command is working but the scheduled task is not working. This is how I have set it up in the Kernel.php:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('import:issues')
      ->withoutOverlapping();

    $schedule->call('App\Magazine\Services\MagazineService@import')
      ->dailyAt('00:00');
}
```

And then in the MagazineService I have a function

```
public static function import()
```

This is the file where I have command setup:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use App\Magazine\Services\MagazineService;

class IssuesImport extends Command
{
    /**
    * The name and signature of the console command.
    *
    * @var string
    */
    protected $signature = 'import:issues';

    /**
    * The console command description.
    *
    * @var string
    */
    protected $description = 'Imports magazine issues';

    /**
     * The Magazine service.
     *
     */
    protected $magazines;

    /**
    * Create a new command instance.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function __construct(MagazineService $magazines)
    {
      parent::__construct();
      $this->magazines = $magazines;
    }

    /**
    * Execute the console command.
    *
    * @return mixed
    */
    public function handle()
    {
      $this->magazines->import();
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us your cron config. How are you determining the task isn't running at all?

Comment: I dont think it will call a static function

Comment: @fire Calling a static function should be fine.

Comment: Can you show your command for the cron job and also what system you have set up.

Comment: I have put a command file @RossWilson. Should I have set up a cron config as well, I thought what I had was enough to run the jos?

Comment: @ceejayoz I have noticed that it wasn't working when I ran my command after some days of doing it for the first time, and the new entries were in my database, which they were supposed to be already if the scheduled task was running

Comment: @Marco The code you've provided does nothing if there's not a cron set up to run it. Read "Starting the Scheduler" at https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/scheduling